# Как записывать данные в суперглобальный массив $_SESSION?

Tags: php

Пишу корзину. Сделать её решил на сессиях.

Застрял на том, что не могу сделать массив товаров. Мне нужно в $_SESSION записывать ID, пробую так:

```
$id = $_POST['product_add'];
$_SESSION['cart'] = $id;
```

В таком случае не получится хранить больше одного товара.

Нагуглил функцию array_push(), но она не работает. С ней пробую так:

```
$id = $_POST['product_add'];
$cart = $_SESSION['cart'] = $id;
array_push($cart, $id);
```

Подскажите, как решить

Comment: $cart на массив не похоже, может так $_SESSION['cart'][] = $id;

Comment: Так вообще синтаксическая ошибка

Comment: `$_SESSION['cart'] = []; array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $id);`

Comment: @InDevX записывает только последний товар

Comment: Ну, это прям костыль.. `$_SESSION['cart'][count($_SESSION['cart'])] = $id;`

Answer (score 0):

Записывай как массив, азбука!

```
$_SESSION['cart'][] = $id;
```

https://onlinegdb.com/F4jJjI9wA